# .htaccess mod rewrite directory index

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to remap index.php file as a directory..

Im real url, it is simply: `localhost/app/index.php?app=my-app`

I am new in mod_write and I know how it really works. I tried to use this:

```
RewriteRule ^app/(.*)/?$ index.php?app=$1 [QSA]
```

And it only works with `localhost/app/my-app`.. now how can I make it work on with or without slashes at the end and also with a filename index.php..

I want something like this:

- localhost/app/my-app
- localhost/app/my-app/
- localhost/app/my-app/index.php (if other filename then error)

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: I updated my question @Blueblazer172

Comment: I just tested this `RewriteRule` at http://htaccess.mwl.be/ and it works perfectly fine. What goal are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: he wants to remove the trailing slash at the end or leave it there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^app/([^/]*)(?:|/|/index\.php)$ index.php?app=$1 [QSA]
```

See [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/OITXTZ/4).

EDIT: Fixes (see comments)

Comment: Thanks! But what if the user entered into other filename instead of index.php ex: localhost/app/my-app/hello.php how can I redirect it to error page?

Comment: Good point.  I fixed the answer above.  Uses `[^/]` instead of `.*?`, which would match everything after the `/` to the end-of-string, including `/hello.php`.